# What is the most used phrase or word that refers to 40's woman?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english

As title, I like to know it both in a gentle way or common use.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you say "vocabulary for 40's women" it is a little unclear. Are you talking about vocabulary that they use or are you talking about a specific word that refers to them. I would rephrase the question as "What is the most used phrase or word that refers to 40's woman?"

Secondly, if you say 40's women you might be mistaken to mean women from the 1940's. For example, "He's a 90's kid." means that he grew up in the 90's. I'm assuming you mean women in their 40's.

So to answer your question I would say, "women in their 40's" if you want to be specific or a "middle-aged woman" if you don't mind the ambiguity. Women in their 40's sounds very precise and factual whereas middle-aged woman might carry some extra connotations that one might take offense to.

Comment: I can't think of a middle-aged person of any gender who would find the term "middle aged" offensive.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I can think of _many_ people, and _certainly_ women who are in their 40's who would most definitely take offence at being called _middle-aged_.